# How to get data from MySql table using PDO and PHP in a select input form

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I am trying to create a form where when the user first selects a country, and then a list off all the cities of the selected county should appear. See the following code:

```
<select name="country" id="countryS">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">RUSSIA</option>
<option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
</select>


<select name="city" id="citiesS">
<option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
```

Then with JQuery I use the following code:

```
    $('#countryS').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;

    $.post('Showcountries.php', { valueSelected: valueSelected}, function(results){

      });
```

And my question is how can I use the above jQuery code so as to be able to show the appropriate cities in the following html code?

```
<select name="city" id="citiesS">
<option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
```

In `showCountries.php` I have stored the following code:

```
<?php
require_once('../class.myclass.php');

if(isset($_POST['valueSelected'])){
  $selectedVal = $_POST['valueSelected'];
  if(!empty($selectedVal)){
                        $locations = new location();
                        $cities = $locations->TheCities($selectedVal);
                        return $cities;
                        }
}

?>
```

And finally in `class.myclass.php` i have the code below which returns all the appropriate cities.

```
<?php
class location
{
private $host = "xxxxxxxx";   
private $user = "xxxxxxxx";   
private $password = "xxxxxxxx";   
private $name = "xxxxxx"; 

public function TheCities($country)  
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->name, $this->user, $this->password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE COUNTRY = :country";
    $sth = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $sth->execute(array(':country' => $country));

    $results = $sth->fetchAll();

    return $results;

}


}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to change your server side code to return json. Loop over the cities you get, and add them to an array, with index as city's id and value as city's name. Then, echo the json_encode($cityArray) instead of return $cities.

Then, in jQuery, you need to construct  elements in like below:

```
 $.post('Showcountries.php', { valueSelected: valueSelected}, function(results){
       var resultsObj = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
       var optionsHTML = '';
       $(resultsObj).each(function() {
           optionsHTML += '<option value="'+ this.cityId +'">'+ this.cityName +'</option>';
       });
       $('#citiesS').html(optionsHTML);
  });
```

Comment: JSON is a preferred way to transmit data between server/client. Its not a language, just data representation. JSON/PHP is the way to go. You cannot return an element and expect it to show up in jQuery. You need to convert it to a form which both jQuery and PHP can understand, and that is JSON.